# Jtree some nodes not selected

Tags: java, jtree

There is some few nodes in my Jtree that when I select them they only expand his childs but they're not selected, in my program, when I select a node automatically it show some information of this node in a right panel, so when I select the nodes with problems they don't show anything, when I select the same node again, it show the information of a random node's child.

When I put the method **setToggleClickCount(2);** the first click on the node show me the right information, it selected well, but in the second click the node expand but not selected, the same problem.

```
tree.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            JTree tree = (JTree) e.getComponent();
            TreePath selPath = tree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
            //tree.setToggleClickCount(2);
            if (selPath != null) {                
                 DBPediaNode node =(DBPediaNode)selPath.getLastPathComponent();
```

Have any idea?

Comment: Try using a tree selection listener. It could be that the mouse click event is followed by an expand event in some cases.

Comment: @Maia Thanks! I implemented tree selection listener and solve the problem.